# put audio file in kafka with spring cloud stream

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

i'm tryning to put an audio file with json in kafka, 
her is the code 
[producer Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CufQi.png)

In the consumer i'm trying to get my file like this [Consumer code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4Twe.png)
the error :

> org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Exception thrown while invoking com.sofrecom.service.VoiceCampaignCreator#process[1 args]; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(StreamListenerMessageHandler.java:56)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
>       at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.DispatchingStreamListenerMessageHandler$ConditionalStreamListenerHandler.handleMessage(DispatchingStreamListenerMessageHandler.java:122)
>       at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.DispatchingStreamListenerMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(DispatchingStreamListenerMessageHandler.java:75)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
>       at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
>       at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148)
>       at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
>       at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89)
>       at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423)
>       at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:292)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:212)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:129)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
>       at org.springframework.integration.channel.FixedSubscriberChannel.send(FixedSubscriberChannel.java:70)
>       at org.springframework.integration.channel.FixedSubscriberChannel.send(FixedSubscriberChannel.java:64)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
>       at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:171)
>       at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.access$000(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:54)
>       at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:288)
>       at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:279)
>       at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter$1.doWithRetry(RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter.java:77)
>       at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter$1.doWithRetry(RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter.java:72)
>       at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:286)
>       at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:179)
>       at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter.java:72)
>       at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter.java:39)
>       at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:771)
>       at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:715)
>       at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.access$2600(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:231)
>       at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer$ListenerInvoker.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1004)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.getSize(DiskFileItem.java:267)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationPart.getSize(ApplicationPart.java:110)
>       at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile.getSize(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:287)
>       at com.sofrecom.service.VoiceCampaignCreator.process(VoiceCampaignCreator.java:44)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:180)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:112)
>       at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(StreamListenerMessageHandler.java:48)
>       ... 42 common frames omitted

any help please !

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems pretty obvious...

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.getSize(DiskFileItem.java:267) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationPart.getSize(ApplicationPart.java:110) at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile.getSize(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:287) at com.sofrecom.service.VoiceCampaignCreator.process(VoiceCampaignCreator.java:44)

It looks like you are trying to decode a web request outside of a web environment. You need to decode the multipart before sending the data to Kafka.

**EDIT**

In `DiskFileItem`...

```
private transient DeferredFileOutputStream dfos;
```

... `dfos` is transient - so it won't get serialized (obviously - because it's a Stream).